# document.getElementById('#ham') doesn't find the element

Tags: javascript, dom

Whenever I add an addEventListener, or a toggle in javascript, I get ''can't read **** of null" or ''can't read of undefined". I tried many different ways to solve it, deleting the javascript file and recreating it, putting everything inside an "addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, ...'), moving the javascript code in html file. Nothing works, I don't know why. I tried all the ways that they say on the internet that work.

```
const hamn= document.getElementById('#ham')

const navLinks= document.getElementById('#navLink')

function openMenu() {
navLinks.classList.toggle('hidden')
}

hamn.addEventListener('click', openMenu)
```

Comment: please add your code to the description that gives the error

Comment: const hamn= document.getElementById('#ham')

const navLinks= document.getElementById('#navLink')

function openMenu() {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('hidden')
}

hamn.addEventListener('click', openMenu)

Comment: Please don't ever post images of code, always add the code as properly formatted text. Please don't add additional information in the comments; instead click 'Edit' below your post and add the information right in the question itself.

Comment: can you add html snippet as well for better understanding?

Comment: `getElementById` already knows you're going to pass an id, so remove the `#` from the string passed to it.

Comment: Remove the #, it is used in jquery. For plain javascript it is needed.

Comment: The # makes it a css selector and not an id attribute.  css selectors are used in both jquery and plain javascript.  for example document.querySelector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` already knows you're going to pass an `id` (hence the `ById` in the name!), so you need to remove the `#` from the string passed to it. The `#` is only used in CSS to express an `id` selector.

You'd only need the `#` if, instead of `getElementById`, you were using `querySelector(cssSelectorString)` which expects you to pass a valid CSS selector.

```js
const hamn= document.getElementById('ham')
const navLinks= document.getElementById('navLink')

function openMenu() {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('hidden')
}

hamn.addEventListener('click', openMenu)
```

Comment: Most likely OP confused JavaScript and JQuery.